# Webpage made using Polymer terminates on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, polymer

I have made a webpage using Polymer. The webpage doesn't open on Google Chrome (both Windows and Android). When I try to open the page, Chrome shows "He's Dead, Jim!" message on Windows and "Aw, Snap!" message on Android. I have reset the settings and reinstalled Chrome but the problem still continues. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem or the reason behind it?

https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B2Zii8voDW6QcGduNnl1cFBReXc/fold/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check if there is any error in your page, which stop polymer initialization:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/debugging.html#unregistered-element-bookmarklet

Btw, did you try the official demo page with your browsers? If they work, then it's your code problem.

Comment: Unregistered Elements Bookmarklet check doesn't work after "He's Dead, Jim!" message is displayed. I have checked the elements which I have created individuality and all elements are registered. The official demo page works in my browser. I can't use inspector element of Chrome after the page has crashed so I have no way to debug my code. Developer tools of Firefox and IE11 don't show any errors.